# about the "modules" in a template file in tornado

Tags: templates, module, tornado

In the tornado demos, an app called blog, 
in the templates/home.html, the code like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ modules.Entry(entry) }}
{% end %}
<div><a href="/archive">{{ _("Archive") }}</a></div>
{% end %}
```

I want to know where is the "modules" come from. I think it should like this:

```
{% module Entry(entry) %}
```

so I changed the code and it works.

Is someone know where the "modules" in template file come from? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a comment on RequestHandler.__init__:

```
# UIModules are available as both `modules` and `_modules` in the
# template namespace.  Historically only `modules` was available
# but could be clobbered by user additions to the namespace.
# The template {% module %} directive looks in `_modules` to avoid
# possible conflicts.
```

I think it may be some codes written in old version of tornado:) So we should use {% module %} instead.

Answer (score 1):

in RequestHandler.__init__ :

```
self.ui["_modules"] = ObjectDict((n, self._ui_module(n, m)) for n, m in
                             application.ui_modules.iteritems())
self.ui["modules"] = self.ui["_modules"]
```

in RequestHandler.render_string:

```
args.update(self.ui)
args.update(kwargs)
return t.generate(**args)
```

RequestHandler is the subclass of your Handler, and render_string has modules in it.